# How to use one .travis.yml file for multiple repositories

Tags: travis-ci

I have several separate github repositories in a github organization for which I want to run the same build test with travis-ci.

That is, I want to be able to use the same .travis.yml for all of these repositories. Moreover, I'd like to be able to update this file and have those changes be valid for each repository.

I could copy the .travis.yml into each repository. But if I have hundred or two hundred repositories, that gets annoying real fast.

Is there anyway to simply point each repository to an external .travis.yml rather than having to put a duplicate .travis.yml file in each repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this with a remote `.travis.yml` file, as Travis-CI will look at the root of the project for this file. An alternative approach I would suggest to accomplish your goal:

- Build automation around updating all of your repository's `.travis.yml` files from a shared common file. Using your favorite scripting language, updating the file in all specified repositories and then pushed to GitHub/GitLab automatically. This should help in maintenance of your repositories with just a bit of extra automated work.

Comment: Do you have any example to extra the common config, especially I am also interested about the shared secret as well.